# Как использовать LowerCaseFilterFactory?

Tags: solr

Делаю поиск на solr. Документы в коллекцию запихал. Пытаюсь искать и заметил, что поиск зависит от регистра. Нашел в документации вот такой код:
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-LowerCaseFilter

```
<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.SuggestStopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"
          words="stopwords.txt" format="wordset"/>
</analyzer>
```

Но я вобще не могу понять, куда его вставлять?
знаю что есть 2 файла конфигурации

**managed-schema** - тут все поля

solrconfig.xml - тут какие то правила

вобщем вставляю в managed-schema и получаю ошибку

```
SolrCore Initialization Failures
addrob: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core addrob: Can't load schema /var/solr/data/gettingstarted/conf/managed-schema: Field type t_name{class=org.apache.solr.schema.TextField,analyzer=org.apache.solr.analysis.TokenizerChain,args={class=solr.TextField}} does not support doc values
```

вставил вот так:

Как я понял, я описал тип t_name и сделал поле OFFNAME_lower типа t_name

```
  <fieldType name="t_name" class="solr.TextField">
   <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>

  <field name="OFFNAME_lower" type="t_name" docValues="true" />
  <field name="OFFNAME" type="strings" docValues="true" indexed="false" stored="true"/> 
  <copyField source="OFFNAME" dest="OFFNAME_lower"/>
```

я уже не знаю как бороться, не могу понять что ему не нравиться. Руки опускаются

Comment: Ребят! опять сам разобрался) убрал параметр docValues у поля OFFNAME_lower